# Compactness yields an affine plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, spheres

Suppose we have a compact set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Then for every unit vector $\hat{v} \in S^{n-1}$ there exists an affine plane $P_{\hat{v}} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P_{\hat{v}}$ is orthogonal to $\hat{v}$ and $P_{\hat{v}}$ divides $X$ into two pieces of equal measure.

This was mentioned in my topology class but I have no idea why it is true and why compactness is required.

Answer (score 3):

Why it's true: A continuity argument. The set is bounded, so if you move the orthogonal hyperplane far enough in either direction, on one side you will have measure zero and the set $X$ will be on the other side. If you take the difference, it will go from $-\mu(X)$ to $\mu(X)$. Also as you move the hyperplane, the difference is continuous, also because $X$ is bounded, so by the intermediate value theorem there is a position where the difference is 0.

You don't need compact but you do need bounded and measurable.

Comment: You don't even need boundedness, just finite measure, right?

Comment: Probably... then you need an extra argument (monotone convergence or such) to show that if the hyperplane is far enough "most" of the measure is on the same side of the hyperplane as the origin.

Answer (score 1):

To mathguy's answer, I would add the following simple counterexample which illustrates the necessity of the hypothesis that the set is compact (or at least of finite measure).  Take $n=1$ and $X=[0,\infty)$.  Then no matter how you cut $X$, one half will have finite measure and the other half will have infinite measure.